# how to load image in image control dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have an image control. After clicking modify button, the image is not loading to the image control. The image is successfully saving, but unable to load it. The images are saved in folder. I wrote following code.

```
 string subs = dTable.Rows[0]["Logo"].ToString();
                    foreach (var file in filePaths)
                    {
                        string sFileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                        if (sFileName == subs)
                        {
                            img.ImageUrl = file;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the `img` control in a container, like a panel for sample:

```
if (sFileName == subs)
{
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
   img.ImageUrl = file;

   pnl.Controls.Add(img);
}
```

in your asp.net page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Seems correct. Also consider using EntityFramework with Linq or an extra validation for the row as well as storing the image in the database if applicable in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection Ocon = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
string sqlQyery = "Select *from StoreFile where ItemId=1";
try
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQyery, Ocon);
    DataTable dtimage = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dtimage);
    if (dtimage.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtimage.Rows)
        {
            Image img1 = new Image();
            // Images Path
            img1.ImageUrl = "~/MyFiles/" + dr["ItemId"].ToString() + "/" + 
            dr["FileName"].ToString();                    
            pnlImages.Controls.Add(img1);

        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```